# Julia: use of pmap with matrices

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I have a question about the use of pmap. I think it's a simple/obvious answer but still can't figure it out! I am currently running a loop where each of 50 iterations is separate and so running it in parallel should be possible and should improve speed. It uses a function that has multiple inputs and outputs, which are both a mixture of vectors and scalars. I need to save the outputs of the function for each of the 50 iterations for later use. Here are the basics of the code when not in parallel.

```
A=Array(Float64, 500,50)
b=Array(Float64,50)

for i in 1:50

    A[:,i],b[i] = func(i,x,y,z)

end
```

Any advice for how to implement this is parallel? I'm using v0.3 Julia.

Thanks in advance.

David

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

```
@everywhere x,y,z = 1,2,3
@everywhere function f(i,x,y,z) 
    sleep(1)
    return(ones(500)*i, i+x+y+z)
end

naive = @time map(i -> f(i,x,y,z), 1:50)
parallel = @time pmap(i -> f(i,x,y,z), 1:50)

A = [x[1] for x in parallel]
b = [x[2] for x in parallel]
```

Let me know if anyone can suggest a more elegant way to get A and b out of the array of tuples that is produced by pmap.

The timings (when run on 8 processes) are as we would expect

```
elapsed time: 5.063214725 seconds (94436 bytes allocated)
elapsed time: 0.815228485 seconds (288864 bytes allocated)
```

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. It's interesting that A is stored as vector of size 50, where each component is a vector of size 500 rather than a matrix of 500 by 50, or 25000 by 1. I can get round this by running: C=Int64[]
for i in 1:50
  C=append!(C,A[i])
end
C=reshape(C,500,50)  Though let me know if there's a better way of doing this. Thanks again for your help.